# Post gets unlocked and locked right after closing

Tags: bug, closed-questions, locked-questions

Is there any explanation as to why [this post](https://superuser.com/posts/577465/revisions) would become unlocked, **then** locked? Curiously enough, the post was edited after that, so it couldn't really have been locked, can it?

[image]

The time stamps for all three actions are the same, by the way.

This happens with some closed questions as far as I can see, for example [this one as well](https://superuser.com/posts/577745/revisions), but [not this one](https://superuser.com/posts/577695/revisions).

Comment: Hmm, it seems the order is simply wrong. There was no previous lock, so the unlock can't have happened at that time. It must have been locked first and then immediately unlocked.

Comment: Even if the order were wrong, what would be the point in locking the post in the first place?

Comment: I have no clue whatsoever...

Comment: I can confirm that the actual order was locked-unlocked-closed, I am still investigating *why*.

Comment: The locking part looks like a migration and migration rejection, which doesn't really make sense in this case.

Comment: @MadScientist Perhaps it does. They might have tried to migrate the question to Stack Overflow, but the OP could very well be question banned there.